# Python code in spyder is not recognizing the variables inside variable explorer

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

I open and run a file1.py using the F5 command in spyder that defines a bunch of variables.
Then I switched to another file2.py that uses those variables in its code but I am getting an error of name blah not defined. Even though I can see that the variable still exists in the variable explorer. If I type in the variable name in the command window, it prints out it's value.

This was not an issue previously but recently I installed  anaconda3 and spyder4.0.1 on a new computer and am getting this error.
Is this a feature or a bug?

If I copy and paste the code in file2.py into the working space, it runs fine.

Edit1:
I tried this simple code and it did not work:
test1.py:

```py
a=2
```

test2.py

```py
print(a)
```

I ran test1.py first then ran test2.py and I got an error of `name 'a' is not defined` while a exist in the variable explorer.

Comment: Please share the code you're using. If you're trying to reference a variable inside a `def` which isn't `global` then you won't be able to access it from terminal for example. Thanks

Comment: I just edited my question to include the code

Comment: Please see the solution to this problem in the question I referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for the working directory?

Comment: Both files are in the same directory which is the same as the working directory